# Как программно получить значение локализации устройства android?

Tags: java, android

Как программно получить значение локализации устройства android,
т.е. какой язык в настройках системы, например ru, en или ge?

Answer (score 5):

объект типа `Locale` со всей инфой о языке можно получить так:

```
Locale.getDefault(); //вернёт что-то типа ru_RU
```

Код языка в 2 буквы можно получить так:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(); //вернёт что-то типа ru
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String country = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();        ru
String country = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry(); Россия
```