# Как менять код в зависимости от локализации приложения?

Tags: android

Я делаю приложение, которое будет поддерживать английскую и русскую локализацию. И если со строковыми ресурсами все понятно, то непонятно как менять код в зависимости от локализации. В приложении я посылаю post-запрос к серверу для получения информации для ее вывода на экран. Для вывода информации на английском языке используется запрос:

```
@GET("/info/{n}")
Call <Info> getInfo(@Path("n") int n);
```

А для вывода на русском:

```
@GET("/info/{n}")
Call <Info> getInfoRu(@Path("n") int n, @Query("lang") String loc);
```

Соответственно в коде они будут вызываться по-разному:

```
Response response1 = requestInterface.getInfo(id).execute();
Response response2 = requestInterface.getInfoRu(id, "ru").execute();
```

Как менять запрос в коде в зависимости от локализации?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628910/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Response response2 = requestInterface.getInfoRu(id, "ru").execute();

Обрати внимание на избыточность, что у тебя не только в имени метода уточняется язык, но и дополнительно передается как параметр. Унифицируй методы и передавай язык как параметр.

В нормальном же случае лучше смотреть на локаль рантайма и в зависимости от него что-то делать: лесенку ифов/свитчей, фектори, шаблонные методы...